# How does one select an option of a custom select component, using JavaScript without any framework code?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, select

With frameworks like Angular 1&2, or libraries like React, there's been an increase in custom `<select>` elements, and, while pretty and all, they become harder to tinker with.

For a random `<select>` element, if I wanted an option selected, I would just use the handy DOM functions and properties that allowed me to select it with no problems.

Keep I'm mind I'm trying to change the value of someone else's custom select, obviously, otherwise the respective frameworks would easily tell you how to wire that thing up.

So now, with all these custom select elements, I don't know where to start, even producing `click` events over the fake select box doesn't seem to work, so I would like to know a general approach of how to solve this issue.

You can take as an example the [**google sign up form**](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?hl=en), with their custom selects for gender, birth month and nationality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would target via the standard methods, such as `document.getElementById()`, or based on their occurrence in the DOM. As for how to target a **specific** element you're struggling with, you'll need to provide the relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not struggling with any particular case, I just took the most notable form I could think of as an example to illustrate the problem, that's why you don't see any code. I do agree it's a pretty vague question though, but maybe someone has some insight. Targetting wouldn't do me any good if I can't change the actual value the select element represents.

Comment: If you want to select an option in "select" component, it would always via "Data Binding", no matter in Angular or React. Is this what you are asking? If yes, I'm glad to offer some examples.

Comment: I understand how it works, what I don't know is how, as an outsider to the enclosed angular or x framework, can I change the select value, a.k.a simulate being a user and picking from the select box.

Comment: ah, I think I understand your question now: Assume there is a web app written by Angular or React or other frameworks, and a custom "select" component is rendered. You want to select a particular option without any framework code (using native JavaScript or jQuery etc.). Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct sir, even if it isn't any framework, just a jQuery plugin, I want to know how one might deal with such situation, where native components are hidden or unused and you need to change or input a value.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: Assume there is a web app written by Angular or React or other frameworks, and a custom "select" component is rendered. OP want to find a general approach to select a particular option without any framework code (using native JavaScript or jQuery etc.).

If there is a *general* approach, it would be very general: Analyse the generated HTML code and change content dynamically. However, it is not recommended, as it would introduce trouble.

**About the solution: analyze generated HTML and change content**

As it is **custom** select component, the generated HTML code could be anything. For example, the [google signup form](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?hl=en) in the question generated a bunch of `<div>` to display the options and selected result, no `select`, no `option`. **Because the generated HTML code is so general (could be any HTML), the solution has to be extremely general correspondingly** -- analyze generated HTML and prepare to accept all possible result.

Here is a simple example using AngularJS: http://jsfiddle.net/cshao/p26muuw9/3/

**Why it's not recommended?**

The above solution only changes the displayed result, the web app's inner state won't be changed, thus introduce inconsistency into web application.

Actually, to change web app's inner state, it's impossible to use native javascript "outside" of framework code (unless by hacking the framework).

Take the above [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cshao/p26muuw9/3/) for example. Even if the selected result text is changed, the web app's `$scope.currentOption` won't be impacted. Actually, it's impossible to change anything inside web app -- native JavaScript outside of framework doesn't even know option's `id`, it just see some plain old bunch of HTML `div`s.

**A workaround**

There is a workaround: retrieve the inner state object of framework (by native JavaScript outside of it), and then manipulate that state object. However, it would be framework specific, different framework may offer different methods. Here is an example in AngularJS: http://jsfiddle.net/cshao/p26muuw9/6/